# Jquery, changing background image with timer

Tags: jquery, image, background

I have two background images I am using for this website and I want them to change automatically every 5 seconds. Can someone please look at my jQuery code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
    var body = $(‘body’);
    var backgrounds = new Array(
        ‘url(images/hso-palmtree-background.jpg)’,
        ‘url(images/hso-boardwalk-background.jpg)’
    );

    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        body.css(
           ‘background’,
            backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
        );

        setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    }

    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    body.css(‘background’, backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Comment: right now it is doing absolutely nothing. There is no background showing. But I know for sure it's getting the images because I set one of them as my background with CSS just to make sure and it did work.

Comment: Ok. The next time you make a question, put that information in it. Now, do you have any errors if you open firebug or something similar?

Comment: No, there are none that is why I am so confused. Is there anyone way of writing this out? Just FYI, I never declared any background image in my actual CSS since I am doing it with Jquery.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You code is correct, you just need to change the backticks. Change `‘` to `'`.

Here is a cleaned revision: http://jsfiddle.net/X2NqX/

```
$(function () {
    var body = $('body');
    var backgrounds = [
      'url(http://static.jsbin.com/images/jsbin_static.png)', 
      'url(http://static.jsbin.com/images/popout.png)'];
    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        body.css(
            'background',
        backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

        setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    }
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Comment: Works good, in my case I had to reset the CSS as it overrode the style sheet, example    mainImg.css({
    'background':backgrounds[0],
    'background-repeat':'repeat-x',
    'background-position':'top',
    'height':'654px',
    'position':'absolute',
    'top':'187px',
    'width':'100%',
    'z-index':'-1',
   });

Comment: How would one add a css-transition to this? Apologies as this question is pretty old.