# How do I create BODY background image slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've searched everywhere for this, I want a simple background slideshow fading images for the site's body background.

I've tried numerous Javascript's that haven't worked and CSS things.

I want my BODY background to be changing, someone has offered me to make a DIV? But if I make a DIV then surely that will completely mess up my sites content having a DIV at the beginning of my BODY...

I know HTML and CSS.

I simply want my body background cycling through and fading, I've seen it on so many sites

I don't understand how can I do this to my body and not just add a little div in my code that will mess up my sites content?

Comment: *Show* what you have tried and explain how it isn't working as desired. I doubt anybody is going to do your work for you.

Comment: already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075468/jquery-changing-background-image-with-timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what effect you are going for you could just add and remove classes to the body using jquery. For instance:

```
$("Body").removeClass("background1");
$("Body").addClass("background2");
$("Body").removeClass("background2");
$("Body").addClass("background1");
```

Comment: Forgot a closing ", I've been up to late apparently.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

Wrapper with div's as the "slides", which can contain any content.

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

Slides need to be absolutely positioned within the wrapper. This has a tiny bit of extra pizazz:

```
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

jQuery JavaScript

Run after DOM is ready.

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

[Try this code](https://jsfiddle.net/jm6a3Ly8/)

Comment: How do I use this for the whole body???

Comment: You can change css a little. [Try this](https://jsfiddle.net/ca2q1k1g/1/). Remove padding, marging, top,left etc.

Comment: I don't understand :( This is changing a DIV's background :( If I put the DIV in my body then surely it will mess up my content? I want to be changing the whole page background :(

Comment: I don't understand when do I run the javascript!

Comment: Ok, I've edited jsfiddle example. You can add `<span class="content">` element inside `<div id="slideshow">` and add in css `.content{  position: absolute;   z-index:10;}`. See changes [Here The link to example](https://jsfiddle.net/ca2q1k1g/2/)

Comment: run the javascript in `<head>` in `$( document ).ready(function(){//code here});` construction. As it should run after all page loaded.

Answer (score 0):

See this simple tutorial for create a background slideshow.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/background-slideshow/

Answer (score 0):

[try this plugin - supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)

download it and include its css and js into your page, then add this code to call it up:

```
jQuery(function($){

        $.supersized(
             //options here
        );
});
```

and see the documentations to use the options that you want.

Answer (score 0):

create a #bg-slider div just after `<body>` element. And define its css like:

```
#bg-slider {
    position: absolute; /*Could be "fixed" if you need it*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0 /*This value should be smaller than the other divs*/
}
```

Now put any slider code in #bg-slider it with 100% width and height, and let it slide. It'll work like charm.

Comment: I don't have a slider code :(

Comment: I don't have slider code :(

Comment: @VenomzHD if you are going to use a javascript fueled slider, use 

http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

it's well documented and easy to use.